# Expanding the size of Flex AIR window on click of a button with sliding down transition effect

Tags: apache-flex

How can I expand an Flex AIR window downwards on click of a button with a sliding down effect.Something similar to the see more details button works when we copy a file from one location to another.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Native Window size and add resize effect when size changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" resizeEffect="{resizeEffect}" width="250" height="183">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function expandButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            nativeWindow.height = //height what ever you like
            nativeWindow.width = //width what ever you like

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <mx:Resize id="resizeEffect" duration="500" />
   </fx:Declarations>
```